# When I add a player it deletes everything in the text file, how do i fix this?

Tags: java

Scroll to the bottom to see the add player code, it deletes everything in the text file rather than adding. Please helm me someone because this is due tomorrow for my high school project. Thanks very much

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
/**
 * Soccer Database, can search statistics of players with several different options. 
 * 
 * @author (Sachin Khargie) 
 * @version (10/1/2014)
 */
public class FinalProject3
{
    static Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner sc2= new Scanner(System.in);    
    static String names[] = {"Angel Di Maria", "Neymar Da Silva Santos", "Leo Messi", "Chrstiano Ronaldo", "Eden Hazard", "Diego Costa", "Benzema", "David De Gea", "Wayne Rooney", "Radamel Falcao", "Sachin Khargie", "Shawn Heaton",};
    static double salary[] = {21000000, 20000000, 22000000, 22000000, 19000000, 18000000, 20000000, 15000000, 16000000, 17000000, 40000000, 40000000};
    static String players[] = {"Angel Di Maria", "Neymar Da Silva Santos", "Leo Messi", "Chrstiano Ronaldo", "Eden Hazard", "Diego Costa", "Benzema", "David De Gea", "Wayne Rooney", "Radamel Falcao", "Sachin Khargie", "Shawn Heaton",};
    static double ratings[] = {86, 86, 93, 92, 88, 85, 85, 85, 86, 88, 95, 95};
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("soccerdata.txt"));
        int menu;
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Soccer Player Database."); 
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println("1. Search for the players salary by name (Press 1)"); 
            System.out.println("2. Search for the Players club (press 2)");
            System.out.println("3. Search for the Players postion (press 3)");
            System.out.println("4. Enter club to find out the players that play for that club (press 4)");
            System.out.println("5. This option will output the salaries of the players then sorts it from lowest to greatest(press 5)");
            System.out.println("6. Enter the players name to find out their rating (press 6)");
            System.out.println("7. This option will output the ratings of the players then sorts it from lowest to greatest (press 7)");
            System.out.println("8. Add a player to the database"); 
            menu = sc.nextInt();


            if (menu == 1)
                nametoSalary();
            else if (menu == 2)
                nametoClub();
            else if (menu == 3)
                nametoPostion();
            else if (menu == 4)
                clubtoPlayer();
            else if (menu == 5)
                sortbySalary();
            else if (menu == 6)
                nametoRating();
            else if (menu == 7)
                sortbyRating();
            else if (menu == 8)
                addPlayer();








    }

}
public static void nametoSalary () throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader i = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("soccerdata.txt"));
        String data=i.readLine();

        String player="";


        System.out.println("Enter the Name of the player:");
        player = sc2.nextLine();


        String salary="";
        boolean found=false;
        while (data!=null)
        {
            String database[]=data.split(",");
            data=i.readLine();
            if (data!=null)
            {
                for (int x=0;x<data.length(); ++x)
                {
                    if (database[0].equalsIgnoreCase(player)) 
                    {
                        salary=database[1];
                        found=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (found==true)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The salary of that player is " + "" + salary);
            System.out.println();
        }   

        else if (found==false)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("That player does not exist in the database");
            System.out.println(); 
        }
    }
public static void nametoClub () throws IOException
    {
         BufferedReader i = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("soccerdata.txt"));
         String data=i.readLine();

         String player="";

         System.out.println("Enter the Name of the player to find out what club they play for:");
         player = sc2.nextLine();
         String club="";
        boolean found=false;
        while (data!=null)
        {
            String database[]=data.split(",");
            data=i.readLine();
            if (data!=null)
            {
                for (int x=0;x<data.length(); ++x)
                {
                    if (database[0].equalsIgnoreCase(player)) 
                    {
                        club=database[2];
                        found=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
         if (found==true)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The club of that player is " + "" + club);
            System.out.println();
        }   

        else if (found==false)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("That player does not exist in the database");
            System.out.println(); 
        }
    }
public static void nametoPostion () throws IOException
    {
         BufferedReader i = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("soccerdata.txt"));
         String data=i.readLine();

         String player="";

         System.out.println("Enter the Name of the player to find out what postion they play for:");
         player = sc2.nextLine();
         String postion="";
        boolean found=false;
        while (data!=null)
        {
            String database[]=data.split(",");
            data=i.readLine();
            if (data!=null)
            {
                for (int x=0;x<data.length(); ++x)
                {
                    if (database[0].equalsIgnoreCase(player)) 
                    {
                        postion=database[3];
                        found=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
         if (found==true)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The postion of that player is " + "" + postion);
            System.out.println();
        }   

        else if (found==false)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("That postion does not exist in the database");
            System.out.println(); 
        }
    }
public static void clubtoPlayer () throws IOException
    {
         BufferedReader i = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("soccerdata.txt"));
         String data=i.readLine();

         String club="";

         System.out.println("Enter the Name of the club to find out what players are playing for that club in the current list");
         club= sc2.nextLine();
         String player="";
        boolean found=false;
        while (data!=null)
        {
            String database[]=data.split(",");
            data=i.readLine();
            if (data!=null)
            {
                for (int x=0;x<data.length(); ++x)
                {
                    if (database[0].equalsIgnoreCase(club)) 
                    {
                        player=database[1];
                        found=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
         if (found==true)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The players that play for that club are " + "" + player);
            System.out.println();
        }   

        else if (found==false)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("That club does not exist in the database");
            System.out.println(); 
        }
    }
public static void sortbySalary()
{
       System.out.println("-------------------------------");
       System.out.println("Original List");
       System.out.println("-------------------------------");
       printThese (names, salary);
       System.out.println("-------------------------------");
       System.out.println("Sorted List");
       sortThese(names,salary);
       System.out.println("-------------------------------");
       printThese (names,salary);
       System.out.println("-------------------------------");
}
public static void printThese(String n[], double m[])
        {
         for (int x=0;x<n.length;++x)
         {
           System.out.println(n[x] + "  " + m[x]);
           }

        }
public static void sortThese(String n[],double m[])
        {
            for (int x=0;x<n.length;++x)
            {
                for (int y=0;y<n.length-1;++y)
                {
                    if (m[y]> m[y+1])
                    {
                        String temp=n[y];
                        n[y]=n[y+1];
                        n[y+1]=temp;

                        double temp2=m[y];
                        m[y]=m[y+1];
                        m[y+1]=temp2;
                       }
                   }


           }


        }
public static void nametoRating () throws IOException
    {
         BufferedReader i = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("soccerdata.txt"));
         String data=i.readLine();

         String player="";

         System.out.println("Enter the Name of the player to find out there rating");
         player= sc2.nextLine();
         String rate="";
        boolean found=false;
        while (data!=null)
        {
            String database[]=data.split(",");
            data=i.readLine();
            if (data!=null)
            {
                for (int x=0;x<data.length(); ++x)
                {
                    if (database[0].equalsIgnoreCase(player)) 
                    {
                        rate=database[4];
                        found=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
         if (found==true)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The players rating is " + "" + rate);
            System.out.println();
        }   

        else if (found==false)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("That player does not exist in the database or the rating has not been entered into the database");
            System.out.println(); 
        }
    }
public static void sortbyRating()
        {
       System.out.println("-------------------------------");
       System.out.println("Original list");
       System.out.println("-------------------------------");
       printThese (players, ratings);
       sortThese(players,ratings);
       System.out.println("-------------------------------");
       System.out.println("Sorted List");
       System.out.println("-------------------------------");
       printThese (players,ratings);
       System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        }
public static void outputThese(String n[], double m[])
        {
         for (int x=0;x<n.length;++x)
         {
           System.out.println(n[x] + "  " + m[x]);
           }

        }
public static void sortThem(String n[],double m[])
        {
            for (int x=0;x<n.length;++x)
            {
                for (int y=0;y<n.length-1;++y)
                {
                    if (m[y]> m[y+1])
                    {
                        String temp=n[y];
                        n[y]=n[y+1];
                        n[y+1]=temp;

                        double temp2=m[y];
                        m[y]=m[y+1];
                        m[y+1]=temp2;
                       }
                   }


           }


        }
public static void addPlayer() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("soccerdata.txt"));
        String data=input.readLine();

        PrintWriter newPlayer= new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("soccerdata.txt"));

        String add="";

        String i[]=new String [5];

        System.out.println("Enter Players Name");
        add = sc.next();
        newPlayer.println(add + ",");

        System.out.println("Enter Players Salary");
        add = sc.next();
        newPlayer.println(add + ",");

        System.out.println("Enter Players Club ");
        add = sc.next();
        newPlayer.println(add + ",");

        System.out.println("Enter Players Postion");
        add = sc.next();
        newPlayer.println(add + ",");

        System.out.println("Enter Players Rating");
        add = sc.next();
        newPlayer.println(add + ",");

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Player has been added to the database.");
        System.out.println(" ");
}
}
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of the text file? E.g. how is the file soccerdata.txt structure?

Comment: Please post only the code that is relevant to your problem. If the problem is in one method, then please post only that method's code.

Comment: send me your email and ill send u you the text file

Answer (score 2):

First, in the `addPlayer` method, you created the `FileWriter` in overwrite mode, which happens by default.  Second, you aren't closing your `PrintWriter`.

Use [the `FileWriter` constructor that takes a `boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter-java.io.File-boolean-) to turn on append mode, and close your `PrintWriter`.

You should also close the `BufferedReader` at the end of the method.

If you're using Java 7 or later, you can use ["try-with-resources"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to have your `BufferedReader` and your `PrintWriter` automatically closed when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Your FileWriter overwrites the file instead of adding to it.

To append, specify so in the constructor

ie:

```
new FileWriter("filename.dat",true);
```

Also, the writes to the disk are not actually made until you flush, so either call flush() on the PrintWriter, or when you construct it, specify that you want it to autoflush, like so:

```
new PrintWriter(fileWriter,true);
```